# Getting name of images per batch in Keras ResNet50 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I'm finetuning a ResNet50 model with a few additional layers using Keras. 
I need to know which images are trained per batch.

The problem I have is that only the imagedata and their labels, but no image names can be passed on in the fit and fit_generator in order to output the image names, which are trained in a batch, to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own generator so you could track what is fed into the network, and do whatever you like with the data (i.e. match indices to images).

Here is a basic example of a generator function which you can build upon:

```
def gen_data():
    x_train = np.random.rand(100, 784)
    y_train = np.random.randint(0, 1, 100)

    i = 0
    while True:  
        indices = np.arange(i*10, 10*i+10)

        # Those are indices being fed to network which can be saved to a file.
        print(indices)
        out = x_train[indices],  y_train[indices]
        i = (i+1) % 10
        yield out
```

And then use `fit_generator` with the new defined generator function:

```
model.fit_generator(gen_data(), steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=20)
```

Comment: I probably don't get the principle of generators.
When I run my program with the above generater (adapted to my data), it prints out lists of indices in a continuous loop.
So there my question goes, how can I know which batch was actually passed and processed during training?

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks!
The overflow of lists of indices came from the max_queue_size setting in the fit_generator. Setting it to 1 makes it a bit easier to understand.